# How do I make my images responsive, max-width isn't working

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make my images responsive and `max-width` isn't working for some reason. At less than 499px the images get cut off on the right side. Website: http://boasish.com

```
/*** Images */
img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The images on that website are responsive.

Comment: Are you using that css or max-width:500px? If you use that, in your question, it will work.

Comment: @rfj001 At less than 499px the images get cut off on the right side.

Comment: @Christina I tried that and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your divs get `width: 510px` property. For example your `<div id="attachment_2469">`. I'm not sure if you are using some script there, but try to remove this property. If you can't you may want to use `!important` which is not good practise.

Try this code:

```
.wp-caption {
    width:100% !important;
}

a img {
    width:100% // sets responsive width
}
```

Remeber, if you can don't use `!important`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this class to the img tag :

```
.img-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: At less than 499px the images are still getting cut off on the right side.

Comment: @k65 first for all, the main tag with the class content have this css:

    .content {
     width: 500px;
     max-width: 100%;
    }

convert it like this: 

    .content {
     max-width: 500px;
     width: 100%;
    }

With JS your are applying to the class "wp-caption aligncenter" a width: 510px. It's bigger than the parent div. Try to set it to width : 100%;

Answer (score 0):

This the css class i usually use:

```
 /*makes an image responsive*/
.responsive-image{

  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width:100%;
  width:100%;

 }
```

Here is a link to a fiddle I created:

http://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/ar6bwpgf/